# I want to find max lenght of string from a tabe in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, max, aggregate-functions

```
SELECT MAX(SELECT MAX(LENGTH(`name`)) count FROM `student_info` 
UNION SELECT MAX(LENGTH(`address`)) count FROM `student_info` 
UNION SELECT MAX(LENGTH(`class`)) count FROM `student_info` 
UNION SELECT MAX(LENGTH(`roll`)) count FROM `student_info` 
UNION SELECT MAX(LENGTH(`subject`)) count FROM `student_info`) 
FROM `student_info`
```

by using similar type of query i want to find one max value of string so i can manage table properly.

what is the proper query for SQLite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for `UNION`.

Get each column's max length with [MAX() aggregate function](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html) and then use [MAX() scalar function](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#max_scalar) to get the greatest of all:

```
SELECT MAX(
         MAX(LENGTH(name)),
         MAX(LENGTH(address)), 
         MAX(LENGTH(class)), 
         MAX(LENGTH(roll)), 
         MAX(LENGTH(subject))
       ) AS max_count 
FROM student_info;
```

Or:

```
SELECT MAX(
         MAX(
           LENGTH(name),
           LENGTH(address), 
           LENGTH(class), 
           LENGTH(roll), 
           LENGTH(subject)
         )
       ) AS max_count 
FROM student_info;
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/fPA4uTuN).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a union limit approach:

```sql
SELECT name, field, field_length
FROM
(
    SELECT 'name' AS name, name AS field, LENGTH(name) AS field_length FROM student_info
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'address', address, LENGTH(address) FROM student_info
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'class', class, LENGTH(class) FROM student_info
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'role', role, LENGTH(role) FROM student_info
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'subject', subject, LENGTH(subject) FROM student_info
) t
ORDER BY field_length DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

The above approach is to form an intermediate table containing two columns, one of which has all strings from the 5 columns of interest, and the other column their length.  We then use a limit query to find the max length entry and the column name.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is mostly correct , just make minor change like below

```sql
SELECT MAX(count) from (
  SELECT MAX(LENGTH(`name`)) count FROM `student_info` 
UNION SELECT MAX(LENGTH(`address`)) count FROM `student_info` 
UNION SELECT MAX(LENGTH(`class`)) count FROM `student_info` 
UNION SELECT MAX(LENGTH(`roll`)) count FROM `student_info` 
UNION SELECT MAX(LENGTH(`subject`)) count FROM `student_info`
) ;
```

[Try Here](https://onecompiler.com/sqlite/3z3g5d333)